# Why should be avoided direct definition of JavaScript Functions in a Web page?

Tags: javascript, html, security, jsp, web

I am working with **Cast** Software ( *Code Quality Analysis Tool* ) and it says that

*"**Avoid direct definition of JavaScript Functions in a Web page**"*.

I have a few samples of violation of that rule.
I am curious about Why Cast determines it  as a security hole or a rule must be obeyed?

Sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about *security hole* (although it does make it easy for people to call your functions themselves, from the console), but the global namespace is incredibly crowded, and defining functions or other variables within it is problematic as there's a lot of potential for conflicts.

To avoid it, you use DOM2-style event handler hookup and wrap everything in a scoping function. E.g.:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton">Try it</button>
```

with

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
    }
})();
```

Beware that there are still browsers in popular (though waning) use that don't have `addEventListener` (IE8, mostly, but I think it's going to be a slow death). But it has `attachEvent`.

Your button doesn't have to have an ID, so long as you can find the element instance somehow. Even IE8 has `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll`, so if you only need to support semi-modern browsers with [QSA support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), you can use any CSS selector:

```
// Get the first 'button' on the page
btn = document.querySelector("button");

// Get the  first 'button' with class 'foo' on the page
btn = document.querySelector("button.foo");

// Get all 'button's with class 'foo' on the page
list = document.querySelectorAll("button.foo");
```

---

This event stuff is one reason people use a browser utility library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Comment: In case you need IE8 support and don't want to use jQuery, etc., here is an example of a cross-browser event listener: https://gist.github.com/rebugger/6208938

Comment: @StephenKaiser: That's quite incomplete. I keep meaning to blog a complete example, I really should get on that so I can use it in questions like this! :-)